# Which ubuntu version suits best my configuration?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, versions

My sister has a netbook with this configration :

```
LG X110-G.A7HBG weiss XP Home
Atom N270 1.60GHz, 1GB RAM, 160GB HDD,
```

Which Ubuntu version should I install on it? I already tried the current version 13.10 but it crashes often and i don't want to repair it again and again.

Could you recommend the version which suits the above specs best?

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty week CPU there, but good enough for [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) (Ubuntu with light XFCE desktop environment).

I would go with [Xubuntu 14.04](http://xubuntu.org/news/tag/14-04/) because it will be stable in 17 days from now as it provides the newest software and it is LTS (long-term support) version, so you will be good with it for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer [Lubuntu 13.10](http://lubuntu.net) for my weaker machines. It will be lightweight enough to run great on your machine but it still has many features.

Lubuntu 13.10 is the newest current version, but I would reccomend waiting a few weeks till 14.04 is released which is a Long Term Support Release